# choose number with specific probability using uniform distribution

Tags: uniform-distribution

Say we must choose between {0, 1} and the probability p stands for choosing 1 for multiple times (e.g.10 times)
So when p=0.8 we choose 1 with 80% and 0 with 20%.  The following R code will do the work. Could someone explain the theoretical background behind it? It looks very common.

```
  ifelse(runif(10)<0.8,1,0)
```

Comment: Are you sure it is $\text{runif}(10)$ and not $\text{runif}(1)$?

Comment: Are you sure about the 10 in runif(10)? runif(1) would choose one number from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Then ifelse would check that value.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I mean draw a number for multiple times.

Comment: The process you've describe is a Bernoulli random variable. For a (continuous) uniform random variable on $[0, 1]$ we have $P(X = 1) = 0.$

Comment: OK the runif(10) will make 10 choices. The ifelse should then produce 10 values each of which is 1 with probability 0.8. I suspect R returns that as a vector of 0s and 1s. It's an R question, not a math question. Perhaps ask instead on https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @EthanBolker, say we just runif(1), how would this uniform distribution produce the result of Bernoulli?

Comment: runif(1) chooses a number between 0 and 1 from the uniform distribution. Testing whether that number is less than 0.8 is like flipping a coin where the probability of heads is 0.8. That's a Bernoulli trial.